# How do you determine the time needed for a sample to get an approximate of the population mean

Tags: sampling

I am doing several tests. Each test is made under different conditions and I want to know how the different conditions affect the results. The test samples are liquids. I am doing only one test under each condition. Usually we ask how many samples we need to be 95% certain the mean falls within a specific interval. In my case I want to know how long should I do each test.

To be more specific on my project. I am creating fish meal in a fish meal plant. I am extracting the fish oil from the raw material and I am changing the control variables on the fish meal plant and using factorial design to determine the optimum settings of the fish meal plant. I want to determine how long each test should take to get 95% confidence that the mean of my output is within a certain interval.

Comment: Why is the concerned quantity here "time"? Not, let's say, "how much liquid"?

Comment: The quantity could also be defined as how much liquid instead of time.